# Why does the 6502 read from the stack before writing it?

Tags: 6502

I am building a W65C02S based computer for fun, and I try to build basically all the tools myself. Including the assembler (yes, I know they exist, I just want to make everything from scratch myself, for fun).

When working on the `JSR` opcode (absolute addressing mode), I find that before it puts the program counter on the stack, it reads one byte off the stack first (program counter is set to `80 2e` at this point, the stack pointer is `01b6`):

```
READ  address:   80 2e   data:   20   JSR   ; Read the opcode
READ  address:   80 2f   data:   14   14    ; Read the LO byte of operand
READ  address:   01 b6   data:   74   't'   ; Read the stack (why?!)
WRITE address:   01 b6   data:   80   ---   ; Write HI byte of PC
WRITE address:   01 b5   data:   30   '0'   ; Write LO byte of PC
READ  address:   80 30   data:   80   80    ; Read HI byte of operand
READ  address:   80 14   data:   8d   STA   ; Read opcode at `80 14` (the JSR operand)
```

It works OK, but what it the reason it reads from the stack first?

(To explain the table: this is from my own tool. I am using an Arduino to look at the data and address buses to see what is happening there. It is a hardware CPU running only my own code.)

Comment: Maybe it is because your tracker is reading the data and address bus to detect and save any change. By this way it may read data during the transition of the control bus (R/W for instance).since your tracker board is faster than 6502 try to add timestamps or save also the control bus status.

Comment: @PaulGhobril the tracker reads on every clock pulse. And this happens only at this point in the code.

Comment: The WDC instruction timing chart confirms your observation and labels it an internal operation (and mentions the original 6502 is in a different order).  Since it has to read or write something every cycle, the easiest option would be PC+1 again, or S.

Comment: but are you going to build the tools to build the assembler yourself too? if not that's cheating.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Erm ... please not another half ass assembler. If you have to do, either be super minimalistic and stay with the original cross assembler syntax (might be implemented in less than a KiB of code) of go for a full fledged real one (read ASSEMBF), worthwhile the time spent.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what tools? [Ask Woz](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17959/6659)!

Comment: oh I used to code in hex too on 6502 (oric), never coded in assembly on that processor either... I even remember counting the bytes for branches, but it was horrible and often ended up in a cpu lockup... I guess Woz was better :)

Comment: @Raffzahn o, it will be half ass. It will only implement the operations I will be needing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no. It has to stop somewhere. But for good measure, I use the highest level language I know: Python. I did build the first steps in a hex editor though.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Ahh, go and look the very first crossassembler up. That's about as pure as 6500 can get :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[This question is kind of duplicate to*

- *[6502 double store and copy protection?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17933/6659)*
- *[What is the MOS 6502 doing on each cycle of an instruction](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17891/6659)?]*

---

### TL;DR:

It's one of the 'dead' or internal cycles of a 6500. On a WDC65C02 they are externally all turned into 'harmless' read cycles.

---

### Background

Unlike other CPUs the 6500 series has not pure internal cycles without memory access, but each and every cycle will as well be a memory cycle. Whenever internal operation can not overlap with with a needed memory cycle, a dummy access is inserted. Usually with the last address used.

- On NMOS it depends on what the next (intended) cycle would be, read or write.
- On CMOS this was changed that the internal cycle would always be a read.

This behaviour will be as well seen on RMW instructions and all inserted carry processing cycles on page crossings.

---

### The Finer Details

The detailed working are described on [page 107](https://archive.org/details/6500-50a_mcs6500pgmmanjan76/page/n121/mode/2up) of the 1976 MCS6500 Microcomputer Family Programming Manual:

[image]

Notable here is that cycle 3 stores the just read ADL, the low byte of the target address, which then gets overwritten in cycle 4 by PCL. This is of course like the NMOS version works.

As mentioned, when the CMOS version was designed one goal was to remove all unintended write operations (*1). In this case the third cycle writing ADL was replaced by a dummy read.

---

P.S.: If you're starting from scratch, it might be a good start to *first* read both 1976 manuals end to end :)

---

*1 - While it doesn't really matter when looking at RAM, unintended writes may screw the workings of I/O ports. The 6500 being mainly meant as an embedded CPU family this counts an important improvement.